# How do you assign multiple values in a key for a table?

Tags: arrays, lua, local-variables

I am trying to assign multiple values for one variable in a table. One for the string name, and one for an integer. The code would go:

```
items = {
potion = "Potion", 100
}
```

I do not know how to formally write this, and how to call for those specific values.
(Do you call it like this?)

```
io.write(item.potion.1) --> Potion
io.write(item.potion.2) --> 100
```

(Or something else?)

Please help. :I

Comment: what your looking for is a nested table like `items = {
potion =  {"Potion", 100 }
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign those values to a table indexed by numbers or identifiers:

```
-- identifiers
items = {
  potion = {name = "Potion", value = 100},
}
print(items.potion.name, items.potion.value)

-- numeric indexes
items = {
  potion = {"Potion", 100},
}
print(items.potion[1], items.potion[2])
```

I personally prefer the former approach (as it's more maintainable, even though a bit more verbose), but either one should work.

Answer (score 1):

Lua allows for multiple assignments to multiple variables.

like so:

```
potion, value = "Potion", 100
```

but this can not be done inside a table definition.

```
items = {
    potion = "Potion", 100
}
```

What your code here is doing is setting `potion` to the value `"Potion"` and then the `,` ends the assignment. The next assignment is 100 which will be assigned to a default key, in this case `1`.

In side a table you end each assignment with a `,` so your tables contents are equal to:

```
items = {
   potion = "Potion",
   [1] = 100
}
```

To accomplish the desired behavior you can nest tables:

```
items = {
   potion = {
       "Potion",
       100
   }
}
```

This example can be accessed like `items.potion[1]` not like `items.potion.1` this is because the `.` notation can't be used with a key that begins with a number.